# Pull data from a Cross Join

Tags: db2, subquery

I am trying to pull a series to columns from 2 tables.  One of these columns is the most recent date comprised of 2 integers, a month and a year.

When I embed the select into the normal query (Max(timestamp_format....)) it returns the first date in the database even with the Max function.  I have tried creating a subquery (Select ... select(timestamp_format... from..) ) and it gives me errors.

I am now trying to create it using a cross join fetching 1 row only and it is still giving me errors.
Here is the relevant part of my query including the where clause and the cross join.

```
T2.Enddate 

From SCDATA.SCCLNT
  Inner Join SCDATA.SCPLHS On SCDATA.SCPLHS.HCLNT = SCDATA.SCCLNT.CCLNT
  Cross Join(
   Select( 
       TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(SCDATA.SCPLHS.HYEAR || '-' || SCDATA.SCPLHS.HMONTH || '-01', 'yy-MM-dd') as EndDate
    From SCDATA.SCPLHS 
  Order By EndDate desc fetch first 1 rows
  )As T2
  )
```

but it is still giving me the same error - after the Timestamp_format() it doesn't recognize any other code - neither as nor from are accepted.

How can I create this query correctly?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with Timestamp_Format? If you are trying to set a format for the concatenation to appear in why don't you rearrange your concatenations in the format you want?

Comment: timestamp_format() function returns a timestamp  (i.e. including the hours/min/seconds/...  and not a date) but your question does not make clear what is the datatype of the join columns for the cross join.

Comment: You have at least one syntax error: it should be `FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY`, although I'd prefer the more idiomatic `MAX` anyways (and possibly as a subquery in the `SELECT`).  What version of DB2 are you on - you can possibly use a windowed `LAST`, which could be used to achieve the same thing.